# Listbuffer behaviour unintuitive... how to solve?

Tags: scala, indexoutofboundsexception, listbuffer

I have a `ListBuffer[MyClass]` and use it as a queue.

Now consider the following code:

```
private def buildChunks(): Unit =
{
    for(a <- 0 until buildQueue.size)
    {
      val chunk: Chunk = buildQueue(a)
      chunk.init()
    //  buildQueue -= chunk
    //  buildQueue.remove(a)
    }
}
```

My problem with understanding boils down to these two lines:

```
buildQueue -= chunk
buildQueue.remove(a)
```

Both of them yield an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` if used (*of course mutually exclusive* I did **not** use them both at once!)

As I said (and as the name implies) the ListBuffer is used as a queue, so if one item is processed I want to remove it from the list.

I do not understand why any of these lines throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException

How am I supposed to remove an Item then?

If you can make me understand this, I would gladly use a prettier approach such as:

```
val chunk: Chunk = buildQueue.remove(a)
```

but of course this doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `chunk.init()`?

Comment: @ccheneson As `chunk.init()` does not change the ListBuffer/Queue I omitted that detail. How is it relevant?

Comment: I thought that `init` could change the queue inside it but if you say it is not, that's fine . I believe Sascha Kolberg ' s explanation is the correct one

Comment: Isn't what you doing here equivalent to `buildQueue foreach (_.init()); buildQueue.clear()` ?

Comment: @Kolmar: I am in fact using buildQueue.clear() outside the loop now. Unfortunately no... I do some more stuff in the loop but I omitted it because it doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem would be that you are changing a mutable collection while iterating over it's values.

In `for(a <- 0 until buildQueue.size)` the value of `buildQueue.size` is evaluated once because `0 until buildQueue.size` creates an immutable `Seq[Int]`.

Now, if your list buffer initially has a size of 5 and you remove one element, it will end up with a size of 4. However, your loop will iterate until index 4, which is no longer present in the list buffer.

One way to fix this would be using a recursive function:

```
private def buildChunks(): Unit = {
  @tailrec
  def buildHead(): Unit = {
    buildQueue.headOption match {
      case None ⇒
        () // end of recursion
      case Some(chunk) ⇒
        chunk.init()
        buildQueue -= chunk
        buildHead()
    }
  }

  buildHead()
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by [Teolha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4063815/teolha) you could as well just do:

```
private def buildChunks(): Unit = {
   buildQueue.foreach(_.init())
   buildQueue.clear()
}
```

which is much shorter and probably more efficient.

**However**, it would not build *chunks* appended to the queue concurrently while `buildChunks()` is executed and in fact might remove any chunks added after `foreach` is started.

Comment: Is using: `buildQueue.clear()` at the end (so outside the loop) less efficient?

Comment: @Teolha There might be concurrency issues. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Teolha I don't think so, as far as I can see, the recursive function takes a chunk from the buffer, call init and then removes it from the buffer. Afterwards it calls itself to process the next head of the current buffer. Only processed chunks are ever removed. The `buildQueue` should at least not loose chunks. If I'm wrong, feel free to enlighten me ;)

Comment: In my case it probably isn't because I'm also changing a HashMap :/